# visual studio application deploy

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I'm trying to create an installer for my application (win form) by visual studio, creating a new project type setup, and am having great difficulty in doing so, for example:

1 When I create the installer and run it installs, but there is the option to uninstall? and I can not install the same application because it already exists on the machine.

2 In dialog window, I see you have the options to create multiple screens and add textbox for example, but where do I set the events of that textbox?

3 º This application works with sqlserver, and I can install it on the machine by the installer, but as I set him to work with my application linq, since I would have to modify the connection string on each machine that I will install the application.

I've researched a lot about these issues and I find no documentation that can teach me how to do this, if anyone knows some please show me,

I appreciate those who can help me, and sorry my english.

Answer (score 0):

I answer your first question at this time due to the lack of time:

1. In VS, right click the setup project. You have 2 options: Install and Uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

1.) You need to uninstall the program through your operating system.  Go to the Control Panel,  Programs and uninstall it.  Then you can try installing the application.

2.) In design view you can double click the textbox.  You will be taken to the method that handles the “TextChanged” event.  Write your code there.

3.) If you are installing on a server you need to create a Web Setup project instead of a Setup project.  The latter installs files into the file system of a target computer;  whereas, the former installs into the virtual directory of a Web server.

Comment: I speak the dialog of the deployment view